# Twilio. Get Active users in chat

Tags: c#, twilio

I need to get active participants from chat.
I joined to video call and try get active users something like that.

```
activeParticipantsCount = ParticipantResource.Read(
                        chat.Sid,
                        ParticipantResource.StatusEnum.Connected)
                        .Count();
```

But ParticipantResource.Read() allways returns 0 participants

there are no errors or exceptions but it returns incorrect value. may be someone faced with such problem and have ideas how to solve it

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're asking about the Twilio C# library, but your profile suggests you are a mobile (Xamarin) developer. Are you trying to run this code in a mobile application or on a server?

Comment: @philnash this is .net core project (backend)

Comment: @Jazb there are no errors or exceptions but it returns incorrect value. may be someone faced with such problem and have ideas how to solve it

Comment: This is weird, I was able to get a list of participants in a video room when I made this call via the Node.js library (I don't have a .NET environment). Are you definitely making this request while the room is still active?

Comment: @philnash Yes, I checked it few times. and checked on just created rooms

Comment: Sounds like it might be an account issue. Can you take this up with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and see if they can help? Thanks!